# regex to validate single spacing between words in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a regex which allows only single spacing between words. Below are the scenatios

1. Test[space]Test - Allow
2. Test[space]Test[space]Test - Allow
3. Test[space][space]Test - Do not allow
4. Test[space][space]Test[space]Test - Do not Allow
5. Test[space][space]Test[space][space]Test - Do not Allow
6. Test - Allow

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = ["Test Test", "Test Test Test", "Test  Test", "Test  Test Test", "Test  Test  Test", "Test"]
var regx = /^(\w+)( \w+)*$/;
str.forEach( test => {
 console.log(test + ' --> ' + regx.test(test));
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Just test for two spaces, if it comes back true, then don't allow, otherwise allow? 
E.g.: `/\ \ /`